# How to completely remove every css properties at once?

Tags: jquery, css

I am loading an external html file with jquery.load(). The external file has inline css and it gets rendered in the main page. How can I disable that css or maybe completely remove css at once.

I have seen solutions like these

```
removeClass()
removeAttr()
```

but with these methods I need to explicitly provide each property.

Comment: If they are inline, maybe you use an HTML5 reset CSS (many available) to load just after the html file...

Comment: Won't removeAttr('style') remove all the inline styles?

Answer (score 0):

Below will filter/search for elements that has the `style` attribute and remove them:

```
$('#content').filter(function() {
    var attr = $(this).attr('style');
    return typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false;
}).removeAttr('style');
```

**sources:**
[removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/), [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [hasAttr](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-an-jquery-hasattr/)

EDIT: `each` not needed, just remove all `style` from the query

EDIT 2: since OP didn't specify the elements to get and based on his comment, this code should do it properly:

```
$('#preview [style]').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: haven't tested this code but I think you get the idea, using `jquery`

Comment: It didn't work.  $('#preview style').remove() did the job.

Comment: that code is not even correct. `$('#preview style')` will get an element called `style`. Using `remove` will remove the entire element as well. Did you mean `$('#preview [style]').removeAttr('style')`?